# prevent app from showing up in googleplay for a specific Android version

Tags: android, google-play

KITKAT 4.4.2 Android has a write access problem on the filesystem and my app is not working.
Can I disable my app in GooglePlay for a specific Android Version like KITKAT ?

Older and newer Versions should be enabled.

Comment: what do you set as target version in manifest?

Comment: Why don't you just fix the app? It's just an extra permission.

Comment: @323go What do you mean with extra permissions ? If you mean android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE . Yes I have of course this permission. As I wrote, its only a problem with KITKAT.

Comment: @donfuxx : <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" android:targetSdkVersion="12"/> . But I like to disable only 4.4.2. 4.4.1 and 4.4.3 and 4.5 and 4.3 should be enabled. Thats because KITKAT behaves buggy ( in my oppinion ) with filesystem permissions.

Comment: Do you have android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?

Comment: The problem is writing. I can read a sqlite database, but not insert into it for example...

Answer (score 0):

Use

`maxSdkVersion="18"`

in your manifest

Comment: Do then older versions before 4.4.2 work also. Is in this case only 4.4.2 disabled. I mean does 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 3.x, 5.x work ?

Comment: in that case the max will be 4.3

Comment: Thanks for helping, but then this will not be the solution.

Comment: @user1344545 : Why not? `<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />`

Answer (score 0):

Use

android:targetSdkVersion="18"

in your manifest